# How to avoid writing \n to file

Tags: ruby

I have the following minimal ruby script to test base64 encoding

```rb
require "base64"

data = "testkjadlskjflkasjfwe08u185u12w3oqew,dmf.smxa"
path = "./example/ruby_data.bin"

encoded = Base64.encode64 data

puts encoded 
open(path, "wb") do |file|
  file << encoded
end
```

However, I have the issue when I read the file in for instance C++, Ruby, or Python there is a newline at the end of the string.
I would like to avoid that. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line feed is generated as part of the encoding process of [`Base64.encode64`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Base64.html#method-i-encode64).

> ### encode64(bin)
>
> Returns the Base64-encoded version of `bin`. This method complies with
> RFC 2045. **Line feeds are added to every 60 encoded characters.**
>
> ```
> require 'base64'
> Base64.encode64("Now is the time for all good coders\nto learn Ruby")
> ```
>
> *Generates:*
>
> ```
> Tm93IGlzIHRoZSB0aW1lIGZvciBhbGwgZ29vZCBjb2RlcnMKdG8gbGVhcm4g
> UnVieQ==
> ```

There is also [`Base64.strict_encode64`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64) which doesn't add any line feeds.

> ### strict_encode64(bin)
>
> Returns the Base64-encoded version of `bin`. This method complies with
> RFC 4648. **No line feeds are added.**

```
data = "testkjadlskjflkasjfwe08u185u12w3oqew,dmf.smxa"
Base64.encode64 data
#=> "dGVzdGtqYWRsc2tqZmxrYXNqZndlMDh1MTg1dTEydzNvcWV3LGRtZi5zbXhh\n"
Base64.strict_encode64 data
#=> "dGVzdGtqYWRsc2tqZmxrYXNqZndlMDh1MTg1dTEydzNvcWV3LGRtZi5zbXhh"
```

With the line feed(s) removed from the encoded string it is also not written to the file.

Comment: :| Really thank you :|

Comment: I have tested it and it works, thanks a lot I had not seen that anywhere thanks

Comment: @LarsNielsen I updated my answer to use `strict_encode64` instead. It generates a base64 encoded string without line feeds to start with.